# Assigning default empty value ("") in the Gson custom serialization for Date field

Tags: java, spring, serialization

I m trying to assign default EMPTY (`""`) value to Date field using custom serializer.

```
@JsonAdapter(AddInfoSerializer.class)
public class AddInfo {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyyMMdd")
    protected Date deliveryDate;
    protected DeliveryTimeZone deliveryTimeZone;
    protected ReturnKit returnKit;

    public Date getDeliveryDate() {
        return deliveryDate;
    }

    public void setDeliveryDate(Date value) {

        this.deliveryDate = value;
    }

    public DeliveryTimeZone getDeliveryTimeZone() {

        return deliveryTimeZone;
    }

    public void setDeliveryTimeZone(DeliveryTimeZone value) {

        this.deliveryTimeZone = value;
    }

    public ReturnKit getReturnKit() {

        return returnKit;
    }

    public void setReturnKit(ReturnKit value) {

        this.returnKit = value;
    }

    public enum DeliveryTimeZone {
        @SerializedName("00")
        OPTIONAL("00"),
        @SerializedName("08")
        ZONE_00_12("08"),
        @SerializedName("12")
        ZONE_12_14("12"),
        @SerializedName("14")
        ZONE_14_16("14"),
        @SerializedName("16")
        ZONE_16_18("16"),
        @SerializedName("18")
        ZONE_18_20("18"),
        @SerializedName("19")
        ZONE_18_21("19"),
        @SerializedName("20")
        ZONE_19_21("20");

        private final String value;

        DeliveryTimeZone(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public enum ReturnKit {
        @SerializedName("1")
        REQUESTED("1"),
        @SerializedName("0")
        NOT_REQUESTED("0"),
        @SerializedName("1")
        ACCOMPANIED_BY_DEVICE("1"),
        @SerializedName("0")
        ALONE("0"),
        @SerializedName("0")
        NOT_NEEDED("0");

        private final String value;

        ReturnKit(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class AddInfoSerializer implements JsonSerializer<AddInfo> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(AddInfo addInfo, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();

        if (addInfo.getDeliveryDate() == null) {
            object.addProperty("deliveryDate", EMPTY);
        } else {
            object.addProperty("deliveryDate", addInfo.getDeliveryDate().toString());
        }
       object.addProperty("deliveryTimeZone",addInfo.getDeliveryTimeZone().toString());
       object.addProperty("returnKit",addInfo.getReturnKit().toString());
        return object;
    }
}
```

```
public class AddInfoIdentification extends AddInfo {

    @NotNull
    protected IdentificationType identificationType;

    public IdentificationType getIdentificationType() {
        return identificationType;
    }

    public void setIdentificationType(IdentificationType value) {
        this.identificationType = value;
    }

    public enum IdentificationType {
        @SerializedName("0")
        UNNECESSARY("0"),
        @SerializedName("1")
        NECESSARY("1");

        private final String value;

        IdentificationType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class ABCRequest :- code

 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder
                .registerTypeAdapter(AddInfo.class, new AddInfoSerializer())
                .create();
        try {
            this.setRequestBody(gson.toJson(this));
            }
```

I m passing object of AddInfoIdentification in jsp page without setting value to deliveryDate field of parent class AddInfo.

deliveryDate parameter should be included in the Json while serialization and set to `""`.

[image: JSP PAGE with no deliveryDate set]

Kindly advice.

Comment: Why should it be set to `""`? It is a `Date` it cannot hold `""` it can be `null` but not `""`. Also you are using `Optional` as a glorified `null` check that isn't what `Optional` is for. Please post code as code not as an image as that is unreadable, requires an additional click etc. that doesn't motivate people to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've added the code. I tried with null instead of "" but still json doesn't contain deliveryDate parameter.

Comment: That won't change a thing because your use of optional (which you shouldn't and it is wrong as well). The edited code with an `if` statement is just wrong. So no that won't work either.

Comment: Can you advice the correct way instead of if block

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? How do you think `""` is displayed in a text field?

Comment: My question is :- Why deliveryDate parameter is not getting added in json at all? null can not be passed to addProperty(String, String)